# Select all columns but ignore records having duplicate values on some of them

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

Let's say I have a `cars` table. It has following columns: `id`, `color`, `engine`, `price`, `upholstery`, `model_name`. So far I've been querying for all cars based on criteria passed from the front end app. However, now I'm told that if multiple cars have the same value of `engine`, `model_name` and `price` they shouldn't be returned as they are duplicates. In this case, one car should be returned with a number of duplicates instead. So I probably need to do some sort of a `group_by` on `engine, model_name, price` but I still need to get values of the other (not-grouped) columns (`id`, `color`, `upholstery`) for each record, as well as duplicates count.

My API needs to stay compliant with the old one. Currently it returns:

```rb
[
  {id: 1, color: 'blue', engine: '2.0', price: 20000, upholstery: 'leather', model_name: 'outback'},
  {id: 2, color: 'red', engine: '2.5', price: 20000, upholstery: 'material', model_name: 'wrx'},
  {id: 3, color: 'yellow', engine: '2.5', price: 20000, upholstery: 'leather', model_name: 'wrx'},
]
```

Now it should be:

```rb
[
  {id: 1, color: 'blue', engine: '2.0', price: 20000, upholstery: 'leather', model_name: 'outback', count: 1},
  {id: 2, color: 'red', engine: '2.5', price: 20000, upholstery: 'material', model_name: 'wrx', count: 2},
]
```

Performance does matter in this case. In reality there's way more columns which are queried and joined from multiple tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `distinct on` and an analytic function:

```
select distinct on (engine, model_name, price) c.*,
       count(*) over (partition by engine, model_name, price) as cnt
from cars c
order by engine, model_name, price;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
WITH duplicates AS (
    SELECT
        MIN(id) AS min_id,
        engine,
        price,
        model_name,
        COUNT(*) AS number_of_duplicates
    FROM
        cars
    GROUP BY
        engine,
        model_name,
        price
)
SELECT
    c.id,
    c.color,
    d.engine,
    d.price,
    c.upholstery,
    d.model_name,
    d.number_of_duplicates
FROM
    cars c
    INNER JOIN duplicates d ON c.id = d.min_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window analytic function `count(..) over (partition by..)` and `row_number()`:

```
select id, color, engine, price, upholstery, model_name, count
  from
  (
    select c.*,
           count(*) over (partition by model_name) as count,
           row_number() over (partition by model_name order by id) as rn
      from cars c
  ) q
 where rn = 1
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=20ffe4da4023eff4f957d73f287fdf81)</kbd>